# android how to save movie object to internal-storage

Tags: android, byte, movie, internal-storage

I'm writing an android application and wondered if there is a way to save a `Movie` object to the internal storage?

I think I have to get the bytes of the `Movie` object somehow, but I'm not sure...
I created the object via the method `decodeStream`...

Kind regards
Marc

Answer (score 0):

[Movie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) is a "stupid" object and you can't get the bytes from it. I would suggest downloading the movie to the local storage first and then creating the `Movie` object from the local file.

Basically you are getting the bytes from `InputStream` then you can save it to a file.

After you save the file you can open it using `decodeFile` function.

There are two main options to save files in android Internal / External storage you can read about them here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

This question deals with downloading a file (and showing progress as well):

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)